# Does $S^2=J_n^2(\lambda) $ imply $S=J_n(\lambda)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $S \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ ,and $J_n(\lambda)$ denotes the Jordan block($\lambda \in \Bbb{R}^+$).  If eigenvalues of $S$ are all positive real numbers. Does $$S^2=J_n^2(\lambda)$$ imply $$S=J_n(\lambda)$$?

Comment: @user1551. I am sorry .I forget to say that $\lambda$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. The key fact (exercise) is the following:

> If $T$ is an **upper triangular [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)**, the set of matrices that commute with $T$ are the upper triangular Toeplitz matrices.

Using this fact, we can prove our assertion as follows:

1. As $S^2=J_n^2(\lambda)$ and $S$ has a positive spectrum, the Jordan form of $S$ must be $J_n(\lambda)$, i.e. $S=PJ_n(\lambda)P^{-1}$ for some real invertible matrix $P$.
2. It follows from $S^2=J_n^2(\lambda)$ that $P$ commutes with $J_n^2(\lambda)$.
3. Hence $P$ is an upper triangular Toeplitz matrix.
4. Therefore $P$ also commutes with $J_n(\lambda)$ and in turn $S=PJ_n(\lambda)P^{-1}=J_n(\lambda)$.