# Let $\mathrm {A,B}$ be matrices does $\mathrm A^k = \mathrm B^k \implies \mathrm A = \mathrm B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B$ be real $n\times n$ matrices with positive eigenvalues. If $A^2 = B^2$, then $A = B$. What about $A^k = B^k, k\geq2$?

Could Anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try a proof by induction.

Answer (score 2):

[Does $S^2=J_n^2(\lambda) $ imply $S=J_n(\lambda)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488421/does-s2-j-n2-lambda-imply-s-j-n-lambda?rq=1)

It seems that this follows from the argument in the above link.